# Though stream is emitting data, streambuilder is not having data . How?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The stream is this

```
Stream<List<OrderAddressModel>> getOrderAddress(String orderStatus) {
    final data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .where('orderModel.deliveryStatus', isEqualTo: orderStatus)
        .snapshots();

    debugPrint("The data is $data");

    return data.map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((document) {
          debugPrint(
              "The data is ${document.data()['orderModel']['deliveryStatus']}");
          return OrderAddressModel.fromJson(document.data());
        }).toList());
  }
```

StreamBuilder is the below:

```
StreamBuilder<List<OrderAddressModel>>(
                stream: BlocProvider.of<UserCubit>(context)
                    .getOrderAddress("Order Placed"),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  debugPrint("Hello there");

                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty == true) {
                    debugPrint("I am having data");
                    final orderAddressModels = snapshot.data!;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: orderAddressModels.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final orderAddressModel = orderAddressModels[index];
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(orderAddressModel.orderModel?.id ?? ''),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              orderAddressModel.addressModel?.fullName ?? ''),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const ShimmerAddress();
                  }

                  return NoDataHelper(
                      iconData: Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                      title: "No Orders Yet",
                      buttonTitle: "Order Now",
                      buttonType: ButtonType.filled,
                      onTap: () => {context.pushNamed(Routes.addressAdd)});
                },
              ),
```

Why doesn't the code inside `snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data?.isNotEmpty == true` is build though i get the ouput from inside the `debugPrint` in the stream like `The data is Order Placed`, it is sure that there is data , but how come it is not executing the code equivalent to that in streambuilder ?

[image]

---

Edit:

```
I/chatty  ( 4989): uid=10156(com.example.vivans_in_10_days) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter ( 4989): The data is Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
I/flutter ( 4989): Snapshot ConnectionState.waiting
I/flutter ( 4989): Snapshot null
I/flutter ( 4989): Icon data is IconData(U+0E156)
Reloaded 1 of 2264 libraries in 838ms (compile: 92 ms, reload: 237 ms, reassemble: 388 ms).
I/flutter ( 4989): The data is Order Placed
I/flutter ( 4989): Snapshot ConnectionState.active
I/flutter ( 4989): Snapshot null
I/flutter ( 4989): Icon data is IconData(U+0F37D)
```

Edit : **Is it concerned to this ?**

```
class OrderAddressModel {
  OrderModel? orderModel;
  AddressModel? addressModel;

  OrderAddressModel({this.orderModel, this.addressModel});

  factory OrderAddressModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return OrderAddressModel(
      orderModel:
          OrderModel.fromJson(json['orderModel'], json['orderModel']['id']),
      addressModel: AddressModel.fromJsonString(json['addressModel']),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "orderModel": orderModel?.toJson(),
        "addressModel": addressModel?.toJsonString(addressModel!.id!),
      };
}
```

Comment: what you see if you do `debugPrint("Hello there $snapshot");`?

Comment: @pskink `Hello there ConnectionState.waiting` ..... then `Hello there ConnectionState.active `.....

Comment: so if it's "active" it means it has some data, what if you print just `snapshot.data`?

Comment: Interestingly both the times it is null

Comment: @pskink Is there fault in the stream , but i dont think so

Comment: I have added the firebase document structure that might help !

Comment: what is the full output (without .....) if you `print(snapshot)`?

Comment: @pskink , find the updated post